# I am trying to match field input for numeric values, first character must be numeric(1-9) and the rest any number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to match with a regex expression input like the following:

```
1        valid
12       valid
321      valid
3214     valid
54678    valid
2a       invalid
131aab   invalid
0        invalid
01       invalid

I tried the following:

/^[1-9][0-9]*/
```

code in a function testing it:

```
var eid = document.forms["frmDelTrukNum"]["empID"].value;
    var eid = callNo.trim();
    var cp = document.forms["frmDelTrukNum"]["cmp"].value;

    var regPattern = /^[1-9][0-9]*/
    if ( !(regPattern.test(eid)) ) {
        lert("Alert[" + eid +"] First character must be a number the rest can be any number   Company: " + cp);
        return false;
    }
```

This line is where I set the regex expression but it doesn't work:

```
    var regPattern = /^[1-9][0-9]*/
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a good tool for testing your regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a `$` at the end to state you want to match the entire string.

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/
```

---

*I am not sure if your `valid` / `invalid` is actually a part of the string you are testing. My assumption is it is not.*

Comment: Thanks that worked. I also noticed that I was using the wrong variable in the javascript so I was changing the value. var eid = callNo.trim(); should be var eid =  eid.trim();

Comment: I just listed a list of sample valid input and sample invalid input. But it is working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jess - glad to help.